# How to convert nested avro GenericRecord to Row

Tags: java, apache-spark, avro, spark-avro

I have a code to convert my avro record to Row using function `avroToRowConverter()`

```
directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        JavaRDD<Row> newRDD= rdd.map(x->{

            Injection<GenericRecord, byte[]> recordInjection = GenericAvroCodecs.toBinary(SchemaRegstryClient.getLatestSchema("poc2"));
            return avroToRowConverter(recordInjection.invert(x._2).get());
            });
```

This function is not working for nested schema `(TYPE= UNION)`.

```
private static Row avroToRowConverter(GenericRecord avroRecord) {
    if (null == avroRecord) {
        return null;
    }
    //GenericData
    Object[] objectArray = new Object[avroRecord.getSchema().getFields().size()];
    StructType structType = (StructType) SchemaConverters.toSqlType(avroRecord.getSchema()).dataType();
    for (Schema.Field field : avroRecord.getSchema().getFields()) {

        if(field.schema().getType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("STRING") || field.schema().getType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("ENUM")){
            objectArray[field.pos()] = ""+avroRecord.get(field.pos());
        }else {
            objectArray[field.pos()] = avroRecord.get(field.pos());
        }
    }

    return new GenericRowWithSchema(objectArray, structType);
}
```

Can anyone suggest how can I convert complex schema to ROW?

Comment: check out my answer on converting RDD[GenericRecord] to DF : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52885103/5957143

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is `SchemaConverters.createConverterToSQL` but it is private unfortunately.
There are PRs to make it public, but they were never merged:

- https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/pull/89
- https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/pull/132

There's a workaround though that we used.

You can expose it by creating a class in `com.databricks.spark.avro` package:

```
package com.databricks.spark.avro

import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType

object MySchemaConversions {
  def createConverterToSQL(avroSchema: Schema, sparkSchema: DataType): (GenericRecord) => Row =
    SchemaConverters.createConverterToSQL(avroSchema, sparkSchema).asInstanceOf[(GenericRecord) => Row]
}
```

Then you can use it in your code like this:

```
final DataType myAvroType = SchemaConverters.toSqlType(MyAvroRecord.getClassSchema()).dataType();

final Function1<GenericRecord, Row> myAvroRecordConverter =
        MySchemaConversions.createConverterToSQL(MyAvroRecord.getClassSchema(), myAvroType);

Row[] convertAvroRecordsToRows(List<GenericRecord> records) {
    return records.stream().map(myAvroRecordConverter::apply).toArray(Row[]::new);
}
```

For one record you can just call it like this:

```
final Row row = myAvroRecordConverter.apply(record);
```

Comment: I was able to compile till the line before return, but since I am new to scala, I am unable to understand the return statement. What should I do for returning the org.apache.spark.sql.Row for this function

Comment: Replace `...` with your list of records. I put it there as a placeholder

Comment: For one Avro record just call `myAvroRecordConverter.apply(avroRecord)`

Comment: `myAvroRecordConverter.apply(avroRecord)` is the one I was looking for, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I've accepted the answer, and sorry I can't upvote since I have less than 15 reputations currently.

Comment: The resulted row does not have schema associated with it, is there a way to retain the schema too?

Comment: @Praneeth maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934615/how-to-introduce-the-schema-in-a-row-in-spark